# Record Type on Process Builder Decision

Tags: process-builder, record-type, criteria

I have a process with a Decision, and in that Decision I want to assess the Record Type of the record that initiated the process, but it does not appear as an option in the Field dropdown of the Set Conditions. It also does not recognise if I try to use `[MySObjectType].RecordType.Name` in a criteria formula.

[image]

How can I assess the Record Type of the record in a process?

Answer (score 1):

When (and only when) the object *has* a record type configured, you can do something like:

```
[TheObject].RecordType.DeveloperName
```

This can be compared then with a string of the record type's API name (which is portable between orgs [production and sandboxes], unlike the record type ID itself).

You can select this in the following way when entering a field on the decision's criteria editor:

[image]